# Remove AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback instance

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I have set `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` for my audio file that works perfect plays in background. I want to remove `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` instance so that i can avoid background play for the some item played by the application player.

```
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

Once it has to be set. cant be retained.
Is there any property for `AVAudioSession` setCategory to remove play back and I can further make it possible by `setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can deactivate the audio session by using following code.

```
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: NO error: nil];
```

and when you want to play the audio again then start the session again by using the code as follows:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
```

Comment: This takes about a 1.5 sec. to wait which is considered "FOREVER" in the applications world.